# ¿Cómo puedo enlazar dos proyectos maven para utilizar las clases de uno en otro?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, maven, java-8

Lo he tratado de incluir así, pero me da error al construir el proyecto con las dependencias:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.controlador</groupId>
    <artifactId>EJBCARGA_ATM_REMOTO_MAVEN</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instala el `jar` en tu repositorio local de Maven:

```
mvn install:install-file
  
-Dfile=<path-to-file>
  -DgroupId=<group-id>
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
  -Dversion=<version>
  -Dpackaging=<packaging>
  -DgeneratePom=true
     
Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
  <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
  <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
  <version>       the version of the file
  <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

Instrucciones: [Frequently Asked Technical Questions](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars)

Creas una dependencia y la agregas manualmente.